# Adding a new member in struct sk_buff - any impact on performance?

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I need to add one small buffer to `sk_buff` structure and want add it as separate member or adding it on top of default `skb->cb`.

The size will be around 100 bytes. Here, the concern is "performance". Can it result in any performance hit for packet processing? Especially, cache alignment, as an `sk_buff` of this size cannot be loaded in a single cache line, could that cause issues?

I did an experiment where I simply added 4 more bytes in `sk_buff`, and noticed that there was 30-50MBps performance drops in regular UDP tests.

Any advice?

Comment: Yep, of course it will impact. This structure has been optimized over years of hard work. What is the main problem? What exactly are trying to do? There is a `cb` special buffer which can be used for your own purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it will have an impact on performance!

Beside possible issues with the alignment of the data structure, the main problem is coming from either a higher **memory diffusion** and/or a bigger **memory bandwidth usage**. Indeed, if the buffer is not completely used, it acts as a big padding. This padding decreases performance because of possibly wasted cache lines or because structure items will not be loaded contiguously from the main memory (this is the case when a traversal of many items of the data structure is needed with only few fields read). Otherwise, if the buffer is fully read/useful, more data need to be loaded from the memory hierarchy (CPU caches & RAM) which is anything but free.

I advise you to just put a (small) **reference** (eg. array cell offset, pointer) to the buffer in this critical `skb_buff` data structure and move this buffer in another **separate data structure**. The benefit is that buffers can be packed and the impact of memory diffusion is significantly reduced (if the added buffers are not often used). However, the downside of this method is an additional indirection/access and the need to manage the separate buffers in a coherent way.